# Estimation of linear wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\phi\in C^\infty([0,T],\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a solution of linear wave equation
$$\sum_{\alpha,\beta=0}^ng^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\alpha\partial_\beta\phi=F$$ where $\partial_\alpha:=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\alpha}, \alpha=0,1,2,\cdots,n$, $t=x_0$,  $g^{\alpha\beta}, F$ are smooth functions in $[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $g^{\alpha\beta}$ is symmetric and $$\sup_{[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^n}\sum_{\alpha,\beta}|g^{\alpha\beta}-\eta^{\alpha\beta}|<\frac{1}{m}\ \ (m\in \mathbb R)$$
where $\eta_{00}=-1, \eta_{ii}=1, i=1,2,\cdots,n$ and $\eta_{\alpha i}=0$ otherwise, $|\partial f|^2:=\sum_{\alpha=0}^n|\partial_\alpha f|^2$.

How to show that there is a constant $C$ such that for any $t\in[0,T]$,
$$\|\partial\phi(t,\cdot)\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}\le C\left(\|\partial\phi(0,\cdot)\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}+\int_0^t\|F(s,\cdot)\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}\mathrm{d}s\right)$$
$$\times\exp\left(\int_0^t\sum_{\alpha,\beta}\|\partial g^{\alpha\beta}(s,\cdot)\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}\mathrm{d}s\right)?$$